# \DeclareMathOperator conflicts with unicode-math

Tags: unicode-math, mathtools

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{microtype}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

% Operators
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\var}{var}

\begin{document}
Let \(X\) be a random variable.  Its expected value is denoted by
\(\E X\), and its variance by \(\var X\).

\(\sin X\) and \(\cos X\) are also random variables.
\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-command-extra-options: "-shell-escape"
%%% TeX-engine: luatex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

The output produced is shown below.  As as evident, `\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}` did not work.  The log did not contain any useful information.

[image: \DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}} does not work properly]

Now, if I load `unicode-math` before `mathtools` and `amsthm`, as in:

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
```

I get the output shown below.  `\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}` appears to work, but other operators such as `\sin`, `\cos`, and the custom `\var` are typeset in italic instead of roman.

[image: \DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}} appears to work, but other operators are typeset in italic]

The documents were typeset using the the following versions of LuaLaTeX, `mathtools`, and `unicode-math`:

```sh
# LuaLaTeX
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.0.4 (TeX Live 2017)

# unicode-math
package:     unicode-math
category:    Package
shortdesc:   Unicode mathematics support for XeTeX and LuaTeX
revision:    46300
cat-version: 0.8k
cat-date:    2018-01-13 15:04:43 +0100

# mathtools
package:     mathtools
category:    Package
shortdesc:   Mathematical tools to use with amsmath
cat-version: 1.21
cat-date:    2018-01-08 15:01:37 +0100
```

Comment: What compiler are you using? I compiled with LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX and both worked, i.e.: the `\mathbb{E}` is displayed correctly and the `\sin` and `\cos` are displayed in an upright font.

Comment: I am using LuaLaTeX along with the latest versions of the respective packages from CTAN.

Comment: The output I get with the exact code you posted using `LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (rev 5238)` is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56Ni2.png).

Comment: Same result as Phelype Oleinik with LuaTeX v. 1.0.4 (TeX Live 2017).

Comment: I added the exact versions of the packages I was using.

Comment: I don't think `\DeclareMathOperator` is (logically) supposed to take commands inside of it which then change the maths font, but I could be wrong. Having said that I'm surprised this doesn't work. Can you please open a bug in the unicode-math issue tracker?

Comment: @WillRobertson This works in legacy documents, so it should also with `unicode-math`. Actually it used to work, I tried on TL 2016 with `unicode-math` version 0.8d. The issue can be reproduced by just doing `\mathrm{\mathbb{E}}`

Comment: @egreg — hmm, I wonder what I changed. (Too many things.) Agree it needs to be fixed. (Should just be a matter of reseting at the beginning of every `\symXX`.)

Comment: This will now be fixed in the next release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a more minimal example of the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
${\operator@font foo}$
${\operator@font \mathbb{foo}}$
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

(The log file shows the nature of the problem, by the way.)

And here is a fix in the short-term:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setoperatorfont\symup
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
${\operator@font foo}$
${\operator@font \mathbb{foo}}$
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

However, the fix will slightly mess up your other operators like `\sin` and `\cos`, depending how fussy you are about such things.

I might need to define more than one operator font!

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Could you please elaborate a bit on to what extent it will mess up `\sin` and `\cos` and the likes?  And yes, I am going to open a bug on the `unicode-math` issue tracker ASAP.

Comment: @d125q the font (may) be slightly different and/or not spaced correctly. You're replacing `\mathrm` by `\symup`, which are superficially similar but come from two separate fonts (a text font in the first case and a unicode maths font in the second).